# How to proportionally resize the background image of a 'div'?

Tags: javascript

I need the `div idPhoto` background image to be scaled proportionally according to the position of the`input range`.

The code is this: https://jsfiddle.net/fjwpvok5/2/

Comment: Can you please explain your problem and describe your attempt ?

Comment: My intention is to make the background image have the same dimensions as the `div idPhoto`. That is, when the `div idPhoto` is resized, the background image will also be resized. In short, it should be in accordance with the link but without using the `img tag`: https://jsfiddle.net/pbyjqtuz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the CSS property `background-size` is what you're looking for.

Depending of what you want, you could use [`cover`, `contain` or `100% 100%`](https://jsfiddle.net/kowry4xt/).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size